# Google Cloud Dataflow output to Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, google-cloud-dataflow

What is the best way to write Google Cloud Dataflow output to Cassandra?

I don't seem to find many people doing it. After searching for a while, the only thing I found was: https://github.com/benjumanji/cassandra-dataflow which has only 3 commits and is 4 months old.

In general, is it a good idea to write Dataflow's output to Cassandra?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible approach would be to implement a custom sink (for batch): https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/custom-io#creating-sinks.

Comment: Alternatively, you can implement writing to Cassandra via custom pTransform. In this case you will have to handle the fault tolerance aspects.

Comment: The "cassandra-dataflow" project on github seems to be doing a mixture of both: it implements a custom transform, but the transform is doing roughly what a custom sink would do.